# Asp.Net MVC and HTML5 PUSH notification

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, push-notification

I would like to have server side event in a full HTML5 application.

Server side I've an asp.net MVC3 web server, which gives HTML pages and JSON results.

What is the best way to integrate some server event? Like a process which can send some text message to client?

I've made some search and found something about a Asp.Net web api, but I don't know what it is and if I can use it with MVC.

Answer (score 11):

You should have a look at http://signalr.net/ library. This [blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx) is also very informative.

Answer (score 5):

SignalR looks very interesting, but maybe more than you really need.  I've often wondered why people don't use Server-Sent Events more often, I haven't had the chance, but it looks like the simplest way of implementing.

Here is an example in MVC if you want to review: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2012/04/10/using-html5-server-sent-events-with-json-and-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Comment: I already viewed your link, but I didn't understood what trigger the new server event?

Comment: You're correct, that article is lacking on information. Good writeup is here on SO: bit.ly/P3Efwm .  And I found a ActionResult here that you may find useful: bit.ly/mIi0D6 I hope you find it useful

Comment: I read your links, but I still don't understand, let's imagine that I've a c# program that has to make my asp.net website send a server event to my client, what is my entry point? Where the event is created?

Comment: That's a great blog post, but AFAIK - IE *still* doesn't support server-sent events! http://caniuse.com/#feat=eventsource

Comment: @JimG. The linked post is not very good, as returning from the controller action closes the connection, forcing the EventSource to reopen the connection after each event. The right way to use server-sent events from MVC (or from standard ASP.NET) is to [write directly to the Response object in some kind of loop](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35678190/111794).

Comment: @J4N See my previous comment.

Comment: That link is a really bad example, you might as well just do a client-side AJAX poll and have done with it.