# server sent events (eventsource) with standard asp.net mvc causing error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, server-sent-events, eventsource

I am trying my hand at server-sent events, but I cannot get it to work within an MVC project (not WebAPI). I haven't found any good samples online.

This is the server-side code I tried (including several failed attempts from various posts):

```
Function GetRows() as ActionResult
    Dim ret = New HttpResponseMessage
    ' ret.Content.w
    ' Return ret

    Response.ContentType = "text/event-stream"
    Response.Write("data: " & "aaaa")
    Dim flag = False
    If flag Then
        For i = 0 To 100
            Response.Write("data: " & i)
        Next
    End If
    Response.Flush()
    'Return Content("Abv")
    'Return Content(("data: {0}\n\n" & DateTime.Now.ToString(), "text/event-stream")
End Function
```

and here is the Javascript

```
var source = new EventSource("/Tool/GetRows");
source.onmessage = function (event) {
    document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML += event.data + "<br>";
};
source.onerror = function (e) {
    console.log(e);
};
```

For some reason it's always going into `onerror`, and there is no information there what type of error it might be.

What am I doing wrong?

BTW, I don't think this action should really return anything, since my understanding is it should only be writing to the stream string by string.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

EventSource [expects a specific format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events#Event_stream_format), and will raise `onerror` if the stream doesn't match that format -- a set of lines of field/value pairs separated by a `:`, with each line ending in a newline character:

```
field: value
field: value
```

`field` can be one of `data`,`event`,`id`,`retry`, or empty for a comment (will be ignored by EventSource).

`data` can span multiple lines, but each of those lines must start with `data:`

Each event trigger has to end with a double newline

```
data: 1
data: second line of message

data: 2
data: second line of second message
```

Note: If you are writing in VB.NET, you can't use the `\n` escape sequence to write newlines; you have to use `vbLf` or `Chr(10)`.

---

As an aside, EventSource is supposed to hold an open connection to the server. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource) (emphasis mine):

> The **EventSource** interface is used to receive server-sent events. It connects to a server over HTTP and receives events in text/event-stream format *without closing the connection*.

Once control exits from an MVC controller method, the result will be packaged up and sent to the client, and the connection will be closed. Part of EventSource is that the client will try reopening the connection, which will once again be immediately closed by the server; the resulting `close -> reopen` cycle can also be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30421945/111794).

Instead of exiting from the method, the method should have some sort of loop that will be continuously writing to the `Response` stream.

---

### Example in VB.NET

```vb
Imports System.Threading
Public Class HomeController
    Inherits Controller

    Sub Message()
        Response.ContentType= "text/event-stream"
        Dim i As Integer
        Do
            i += 1
            Response.Write("data: DateTime = " & Now & vbLf)
            Response.Write("data: Iteration = " & i & vbLf)
            Response.Write(vbLf)
            Response.Flush

            'The timing of data sent to the client is determined by the Sleep interval (and latency)
            Thread.Sleep(1000) 
        Loop
    End Sub
End Class
```

---

### Example in C#

Client-side:

```
<input type="text" id="userid" placeholder="UserID" /><br />
<input type="button" id="ping" value="Ping" />

<script>
    var es = new EventSource('/home/message');
    es.onmessage = function (e) {
        console.log(e.data);
    };
    es.onerror = function () {
        console.log(arguments);
    };

    $(function () {
        $('#ping').on('click', function () {
            $.post('/home/ping', {
                UserID: $('#userid').val() || 0
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Server-side:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace EventSourceTest2.Controllers {
    public class PingData {
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public class HomeController : Controller {
        public ActionResult Index() {
            return View();
        }

        static ConcurrentQueue<PingData> pings = new ConcurrentQueue<PingData>();

        public void Ping(int userID) {
            pings.Enqueue(new PingData { UserID = userID });
        }

        public void Message() {
            Response.ContentType = "text/event-stream";
            do {
                PingData nextPing;
                if (pings.TryDequeue(out nextPing)) {
                    Response.Write("data:" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(nextPing, Formatting.None) + "\n\n");
                }
                Response.Flush();
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            } while (true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks zev for the clear and detailed instructions. its wroking now!!